# script for creation trigger(s), which will implement autoincrement of artifical keys

Tags: postgresql

when inserting to table it will set value of primary key (id) to next value from sequence to ensure that the user of DB does not need to write correct id (it will be generated by trigger).

Comment: No triggers required

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a trigger, you need an identity column using `generated as identity` to set that columns as auto increment

```
create table tablename(
 id int not null generated always as identity primary key
  , col1
  , col2 
  , col3
)
```

so then you don't need to mention it whenever you insert into that table :

```
insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3) values (val1,val2,val3)
```